# Jupyter Lab export as executable save location

Tags: jupyter

I'd like to save an executable version of a python kernel notebook in the same directory as the actual notebook. Exporting as executable currently puts a download in the downloads folder (OSX). Is there a variable I need to change so that executables are saved in current directory?